# the array inside of the state is always undefind when using pinia

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I am using pinia in my vue3 projects and for some reason I am trying to store some temporary data in pinia, here is my store file:

```
// template.ts
export const useTemplateStore = defineStore('template', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      templates: [] as Template[],
      temporary: {
        id: generateUUID(),
        itemList: []
      } as Template
    }
  },
  actions: {
    reset() {
      this.temporary = {
        id: generateUUID(),
        itemList: []
      }
    },
    addItem(item: TemplateItem) {
      this.temporary.itemList.push(item);
    }
  }
})
```

But when I tried to push item into `temporary.itemList` in my vue file, it failed:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
// ...
const useTemplate = useTemplateStore();
// both of them failed
useTemplate.addItem({ ... });
useTemplate.temporary.itemList.push({ ... });
</script>
```

when I checked the console, it showed:
[directly push](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ono2h.png)
[using addItem method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ikdO.png)

I log the `itemList` out(`console.log(useTemplate.temporary.itemList)`), and the result is `undefined`.

where is the problem? it bothers me very much，so if anyone can help me out I'd appreciate it.

By the way, my projects is coding with typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be something caused by `TypeScript`.

The `JavaScript` version works well.

```js
const { createApp } = Vue
const { createPinia, defineStore } = Pinia

const useTemplateStore = defineStore('template', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      templates: [],
      temporary: {
        itemList: []
      } 
    }
  },
  actions: {
    reset() {
      this.temporary = {
        itemList: []
      }
    },
    addItem(item) {
      this.temporary.itemList.push(item);
    }
  }
})

const App = {
  setup() {
    const useTemplate = useTemplateStore();
    // both of them failed
    useTemplate.addItem({ item: 1 });
    const addItem2 = () => { 
      useTemplate.temporary.itemList.push({ item: useTemplate.temporary.itemList.length + 1}) 
    }
    return {
      useTemplate,
      addItem2
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
const pinia = createPinia()
app.use(pinia)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  useTemplate.temporary.itemList: {{ useTemplate.temporary.itemList }}<br/>
  <button @click="addItem2()">Add Item</button>&nbsp;
  <button @click="useTemplate.reset()">Reset</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-demi@0.13.11/lib/index.iife.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pinia@2.0.30/dist/pinia.iife.js"></script>
```

Comment: is there any way I can fixed it with typescript? cuz I don't want to change the language in my projects...

Comment: I am not really familiar with TypeScript, but I got it working. Here is the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-dhawan-t62q8h)

Comment: I tried to set up a new TypeScript project, and it also works well...maybe it was caused by some dependencies of the previous project. Anyway, thank you very much for your help.